# How to validation in perl

Tags: xml, linux, perl, validation

I am working on a perl script which takes as input path to directory in linux.
Directory has xml files in it. Perl script iterates through all the xml files and convert each xml file into json format.

I have my code written and working properly but i am stuck at validation conditions in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON;
use XML::Simple;
use File::Spec;

$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 1) {
    print "\nUsage: $0 <input directory>\n";
exit;
}

my $dirPath = $ARGV[0];
if (not -e $dirPath)
{
    $dirPath = "/opt/poll/";
}        

opendir(DIR, $dirPath);
my @docs = grep(/\.xml$/,readdir(DIR));

foreach my $file (@docs) 
{
    my $abs_path = join("",$dir,$file);
    my $json_object = xml2json($abs_path);
    print_json($json_object);
}

sub print_json
{
   my $json_object = $_[0];
   print $json_object;
 }

 sub xml2json
{
   my $filename = $_[0];
   #print $filename;:q!
   #print "\n";
   # Create the object of XML Simple
   my $xmlSimple = new XML::Simple(KeepRoot   => 1);

   # Load the xml file in object
   my $dataXML = $xmlSimple->XMLin($filename);

   # use encode json function to convert xml object in json.
   my $jsonString = encode_json($dataXML);

   #print $jsonString;
   return $jsonString;
  }
```

few validation i am planning to test the corner cases:

1> `opendir(DIR, $dirPath);`   :  if `opendir` fails to open the directory how to handle this case?

2>  How to check that the `xml` files exists and can be read first. Otheriwse the `XMLSimple` constructor could throw an unhandled exception.

3> How to handle condition when input `xml` file is empty or input `xml` file is corrupt.

4> What if `$dataXML` is undef?

I am new to perl so having troubles reading through its documentation and get the solution. Though i was able to wrote the whole script.

Let me know if any suggestions.
I tried using `eval` here in above cases but not sure how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1) `opendir(my $dir, $dirPath) or die "Failed to open $dirPath: $!"`

2) `die "$file not readable" unless -r $file`

You can also use `die "$file does not exist" unless -e $file` if you want to distinguish between "file does not exist" and "file exists, but is not readable", but `-r` will catch both, since a nonexistent file is also unreadable.

3) Your XML parser should already handle those conditions.  Indeed, I'm not sure how you'd determine that the XML is corrupt other than by parsing it.

4) `unless (defined $dataXML) { ... die or do whatever else you want to do when its undef ... }`

None of these things strike me as clear cases for use of `eval` - `eval` prevents code from dying so you can try to recover, but, in most of these cases, any error would be unrecoverable, unless you mean to just skip over the bad file.  If that's what you wanted, then just replace `die` with `next` or something like

```
unless (-r $file) {
  warn "$file not readable";
  next;
}
```

to provide a report of the error in addition to skipping over it.

Comment: `die $!` will do a lot of the handling of different conditions. E.g. if you're doing an `open` it'll report the OS error - permission denied, file not found, etc. So you don't really need to test each case. You just need 'did it work'.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a slightly different approach - validation is less necessary if you trap return codes.

Perl has a useful pragma for doing this - `autodie`.

Switch on `use autodie;` and every file open, close and a few others becomes a fatal error.

I would also suggest - don't use [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm). From the docs:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged.

`XML::Simple` is for simple XML. I would suggest looking [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) as a better alternative.

Anyway, for your specific queries:

1/ `opendir` or `die $!`. Or `use autodie;` Or - in my opinion, better yet - don't use `opendir` and `grep` but instead use [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

```
foreach my $file ( <$dirpath/*.xml> ) {

}
```

If there's nothing appropriate, then this will be a null loop.

Given you already test for `$ARGV[0]` I would suggest it's bad practice to 'default' to a different path if that's invalid. That means your script might do something unexpected, and that's bad style. If I give you an invalid path, you should bomb out and tell me, not do something else entirely.

2/ `open` will autodie. `XML::Twig` `parsefile` will also die on failures. (invalid xml, unreadable etc.)

3/ Irrelevant - either XML is valid and can be parsed, or it's fatal. XML parsers will simply die.

4/ It won't be, because your parser will have already triggered a `die` condition.

Now, all this talk of `die` calls might seem like it's drastic. It's not as bad as it sounds - for starters, the XML spec *requires* that invalid XML is a fatal error - it's not allowed to try and 'figure it out' (like your browser would with shoddy HTML).

You can use `eval` to trap `die` if you need to. From: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html

```
# make divide-by-zero nonfatal
eval { $answer = $a / $b; }; warn $@ if $@;
```